# FFMPEG: 10 second video from still image is not 10 seconds long when uploaded to Instagram

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a 10 second video from a still image and an audio clip. I'm using these clips for marketing on Instagram Stories but when Instagram finishes processing the video, it seems to only be one frame long. It plays for 10 seconds everywhere else I've tried (on various desktop players, on my phone, etc).

Here's the FFMPEG line I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -r 1/10 -i image.png -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -r 1/10 -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -shortest -t 10 out.mp4
```

I've played around with different frame rates and with taking out the `-tune stillimage` flag. I'm no expert with FFMPEG so I'm not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop the image:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -framerate 1/10 -i image.png -i audio.mp3 -c:v libx264 -tune stillimage -c:a aac -r 10 -b:a 192k -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 10 out.mp4
```